# 9th grade trig question

Tags: trigonometry

*At point, S, lies between a flagpole, 10 metres high, and a tower, 16 metres tall. Sophie is standing between the flagpole and the tower. From Sophie's position, the angle of elevation to the top of the flagpole is 34° and to the top of the tower is 73°.*

*Calculate the direct distance between the base of the flagpole and the bottom of the tower.*

I drew a diagram and *tried* to answer it. The correct answer is supposed to be 26.78m
[image]

But as I was crying (maybe srs) trying to find a solution I found that if I switch the 10 and 16 around I'd get 26.78m... wat.

Did I do it wrong the first time? Please explain this to me.

Comment: Your method (and answer) are  correct.

Comment: As a side comment, $4$ significant digit accuracy cannot be expected here. The angles are presumably correct to only $2$ significant figures, and there are issues unless Sophie is *extremely* short or lying on the ground.

Comment: Your solution is correct.
(Why would you switch the 10 and 16?)

Comment: I guess my textbook was wrong!

Comment: Thanks, guys

@naslundx I-I was just experimenting ;__;

Comment: No harm in that @Serein :) Just remember that the 34 degree angle belongs to the triangle with side 10, and the 73 degree angle belongs to the triangle with side 16, so switching them makes no sense.